# why doesn't work "filter" and "any" functions in my R code?

Tags: r

My code is at below. I have 56 days glucose days (every 5 min) and I expect that the filter function select the only 4 hours data in particular condition. Until the end of selected glucose data, it worked correctly but the last data finished 1.5 hour later (because the full data finished). So the filter function shouldn't select that because this has not 4 hours. But it included that one. I don't understand why it was included. Do you have any solution for that? Also I wonder the reason... Many thanks

```
 Df1 <- NULL
 for (i in 1:nrow(SelectedGluc)){
 start <- SelectedGluc$Time_Glucose[i]
 end <- start+(4*60*60)
 Analysis <- Glu_Full_Data %>% rowwise() %>%
    filter(any(Time_Glucose >= start & Time_Glucose <= end))
 Df1 <- rbind(Df1, data.frame(Meal_Number=SelectedGluc$Meal_Number[i], 
              Time_Glucose=Analysis$Time_Glucose, Gluc=Analysis$Glucose))
 }
```

My example data are

```
 My SelectedGlu data
   Meal_Number  Time_Glucose          
 1           1  2019-10-26 08:30:00    
 2           2  2019-10-26 15:10:00     
 3           3  2019-10-26 21:20:00      
 4           4  2019-10-27 07:30:00  
 5           5  2019-10-27 12:30:00 
 6           6  2019-10-27 18:30:00 

 Glu_Full_Data
          Time_Glucose  Glucose
 1 2019-10-25 22:00:00   6.995
 2 2019-10-25 22:05:00   6.995
 3 2019-10-25 22:10:00   6.939  
 4 2019-10-25 22:15:00   6.884
 5 2019-10-25 22:20:00   6.995
 6 2019-10-25 22:25:00   7.105   # nearly 16000 values
```

For example the time for selected glucose is Meal_Number 1 "2019-10-26 08:38:00". The code will pick the selected time and go to Glu_Full_Data and find the selected time (2019-10-26 08:38:00). Then filter the data of glucose from this time to four hours later (between these two times).
The last selected time is "2019-12-18 20:00" and Glu_Full_Data is finish "2019-12-18 22:00". I expect the code shouldn't include this because the data is not 4 hours data. But in my output it was included.
I wonder the reason and how can I solve it?

Comment: I guess you can remove the rowwise

Comment: Can you share `dput(head(Glu_Full_Data))` and `dput(head(SelectedGlu))` instead? It'll make your question more reprodcible

Comment: which rowrise? I didn't understand  @akrun

Comment: @user21528954 your code shows `Glu_Full_Data %>% rowwise()`

Comment: the system didn't accept that due to its length.  do you have a chance to give a suggestion with this information? @Maël

Comment: `dput(head(Glu_Full_Data))` should only give the six first rows. I doubt this will cause a problem in terms of length. Don't forget the `head`

Comment: It didn't change / work  @akrun

Comment: I corrected @Maël

Comment: Is there anyone help me? I am really struggling with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Are your sure, that you are using the right library for filtering? Try `dplyr::filter(any(Time_Glucose >= start & Time_Glucose <= end))`

Comment: yes, i checked again everything and it iscorrect @DaN

Comment: I think you should add a library that can handle time formats and also calculates with time, because you have date and time in on field, you should give this format to the data frame or calculation in filter. Maybe use something like: `difftime(time2, time2, units="hours") .

Comment: It is same format in data frame and filter calculation.  @DaN

Comment: yeah, but does R know it is date/time or something else?

Comment: yes because I used this time format (in these two df) together in different coding and they worked

Comment: which libraries do you imported ?

Comment: If dou you mean that Glu_Full_Data$Time_Glucose <- as.POSIXlt(Glu_Full_Data$Time_Glucose,format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") and also Selected_Glu$Time_Glucose was created from the format of Glu_Full_Data$Time_Glucose @DaN

Comment: I still couldn't find a solution to my problem. Is there anyone that can help me?